# Laravel 7.4 cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, laravel-7, laravel-migrations

So I'm creating a migration file following the `template` of my old one as follows:

##### `create_banners_table` (this one **WORKED**)

```php
class CreateBannersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('banners', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('order');
            $table->string('published');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('banner_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('locale', 10)->index();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->foreignId('banner_id')
                ->constrained()
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('banner_translations');
        Schema::dropIfExists('banners');
    }
}
```

Here's the `create_managements_table` (this one **FAILED**):

```php
class CreateManagementsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('managements', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('order');
            $table->string('published');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('category')
                ->comment('board of commissioners', 'board of executives');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('management_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('locale', 10)->index();
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->foreignId('management_id')
                ->constrained()
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('management_translations');
        Schema::dropIfExists('managements');
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I tried to make another migration file based on that, I got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `management_translations` add constraint `management_translations_management_id_foreign` foreign key (`management_id`) references `management` (`id`) on delete cascade)
```

As you can see both of the translation table references the big integer in their respective base table (so there is no type mismatch).

For further investigation, I ran `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`
and checked the `Latest Foreign Key Error` and got the following:

```
------------------------
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2021-08-28 12:01:41 0x7f6f44091700 Error in foreign key constraint of table cemindo/#sql-200_7:
 foreign key (`management_id`) references `management` (`id`) on delete cascade:
Cannot resolve table name close to:
 (`id`) on delete cascade
```

Comment: change `$table->bigIncrements('id');` and `$table->increments('id')->unsigned();` to `$table->id();` it will solve your problem

Comment: ...I already did for both of referenced Ids to the respective base tables

bigIncrement worked just fine for **Banner**, but failed for **Management**... Idk why

Comment: And changing both to `$table->id();` still results in the same error

Comment: Personal recommendation, never use MySQL's `foreign` relations, they will only give you these problems. If your code is correct, you should still have everything deleted as if the `foreign` was present. Also, use `id();` instead of `increments` as you are not defining it correctly... You have to tell it is an `id` and you do so with `id` or `bigIncrements`. And also, **super important**, do not use a migration to do more than 1 creation at a time, it is 100% recommended to have each table created in a separate migration even if they are related, you can rollback EACH in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not the word `management` countable is ambiguous so apparently Laravel treats it as uncountable in this case. That's to say that Laravel thinks the corresponding table name for `management_id` would be `management` not `managements` which is an uncommon plural form. Therefore you either should rename your base table to `management` or use the following foreign key sytnax:

```
Schema::create('management_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {    
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('locale', 10)->index();
    $table->string('description');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->foreignId('management_id')
        ->constrained('managements')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema::create('banner_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('banner_id')->unsigned();     //change this line
            $table->string('locale', 10)->index();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->foreignId('banner_id')
                ->constrained()
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

I think you should provide banner_id first and then provide foreignId.(same column name)

Comment: no... the `banner` table is working _perfectly fine_, it's the `management` table that's acting up

Answer (score 0):

you can add foreign key reference as like below,

first create all the keys then at last declare the foreign key reference ... you can see this method at [Laravel Doc's](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) ... See First example of that link

```
Schema::create('managements', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('order');
        $table->string('published');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('category')
            ->comment('board of commissioners','board of executives');
        $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('management_translations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('locale', 10)->index();
        $table->string('description');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('management_id');
        $table->foreign('management_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('managements');
                ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

If you face any error using my solution let me know, I will update my answer

Thank you